# Template class causes destructor being called twice

Tags: c++, templates

I have a pipe-filtern Template class. The class template looks like this:

```
template<class T, class O, class F>
class hdm::filter::Filter
```

T is the input type class, O the output type. F is the concrete filter class that implements the filter - but this should be irrelevant for now.

The run loop of the filter template class is this:

```
void run() noexcept
    {
        pthread_setname_np(getThreadName());
        while(_running) {
            T obj;
            _skip = false;
            while(!_inputqueue->wait_dequeue_timed(obj,chrono::milliseconds(IDLE_LOOP)) && _running);
            if(!_running) break;
            O objout = reinterpret_cast<F*>(this)->process(obj);
            if(_outputqueue != nullptr && !_skip) {
                push_results(objout);
            }
        }
    }
```

In one of the concrete filter classes, the object "O" handled by the filter template class is constructed like so:

```
std::vector<CellLoadInfo*>* referencedCells = new std::vector<CellLoadInfo*>;
```

The next filter just gets a CellLoadInfo object.

Now even though this is a pointer object, it seems that the destructor of CellLoadInfo gets called twice when the object get's out of scope of the run-loop of the filter above.

Why is it being called twice, and how to avoid it?

Comment: Since you failed to provide a [mcve], no answer is possible. But generally, when you start doing things like throwing `reinterpret_cast` all over the place, it won't be a surprise if a subtle bug ends up introducing these kinds of results.

Comment: I've updated the question. Note the reinterpret_cast is implemented in the filter template class, not in the concrete filter. I could avoid the cast otherwise.

Comment: No destructors are called when a pointer variable's scope ends. What is the object "O" that has this type? There's an "O" *type*, but no object.

Comment: And why do you think the concrete template parameters are irrelevant? Furthermore, what exactly do you expect us to make of the run function? It uses a bunch of members, the types of which are unknown to us.

Comment: O is CellLoadInfo. The next filter just gets a dereferenced item from the vector.